# My third party CRM Integration Clientify is not receiving some messenger chats

Tags: facebook

I'm using third party CRM Clientify to manage all my business conversations, I Integrated Whatsapp, Instagram and Messenger, with the latter not receiving all messages, there are some messages that land in the CRM, Some don't. Using a test device, I can see that my business chat, at the bottom, has a button labeled "Unsubscribe", but I'm not sure if that's the reason why chat's aren't being received by the CRM. If so, what can I do to remove the unsubscribe button? Or how can I troubleshoot what is causing the issue?

[image]

[image]